# How to setup a Python socket on and IPv6 address?

Tags: python, python-sockets

I was making a quiz program for a school project with Python and in that, I was trying to implement some kind of server-client model so that my database of questions and scores stays on one central server. Anyways, I saw a few videos and read through some documentation, and understood sockets well enough to implement the `socket.AF_INET` connection successfully.

Now that was fine for the LAN in the school but I wanted to take it a step further and have some way of connecting to it over the internet from outside that LAN. I got to know that for that I'll need to bind my socket to an IPv6 address through `socket.AF_INET6` but there is no tutorial or anything explaining that and I can't seem to understand the docs for it.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could just explain to me how to use the `socket.AF_INET6` parameter in both the `socket.bind()` method for the server and the `socket.connect()` method for the client. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? There are both documentation and examples online that should help you out. Show us your code and explain the *specific* error messages or unexpected behavior that you're seeing.